# django and twitter bootstrap does not work correctly in IE8

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use twitter bootstrap's navigation bar in the django template. I put the following in the head of the "base.html".

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The page looks right in chrome. But when I change to IE8, the CSS is messed up. The "container" is no longer centered and the navigation bar does not look right.

Then I tried getting rid of django. I moved the bootstrap.css into the folder of base.html, and changed the css loading to:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then I open the base.html in IE directly, and everything looks correct again. So it seems in IE8, the django template rendering is messing up with the bootstrap's css somehow. Any idea? Thanks.

====== copied fro IE8 "view-source" =========

with django template rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN" autopagermatchedrules="1">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>AAA</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
              padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">

              <a class="brand" href="/">AAA</a>
              <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="/">
                    BBB
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">
                    CCC
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

without django template rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN" autopagermatchedrules="1">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
              padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">

              <a class="brand" href="/">AAA</a>
              <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="/">
                    BBB
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">
                    CCC
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

=====================================
I just found that if I put the following code into "base.html" and extend it in "main.html", IE8 does not work well. But if I move them to "main.html", and does not use django "extend", it is OK.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN" autopagermatchedrules="1">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
        <style>
            body {
              padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the "view-source" code in IE for both cases?

Comment: There shouldn't be any clash, you're assumption that it's something with rendering doesn't make sense. There's no trouble between extend and IE8 (I'm saying that out of experience). You probably didn't configure your static files correctly. Can you share settings.py and other related stuff? Also, show us your extended HTML (maybe you misused extend correctly?). You need content blocks, it's not enough to use extend

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @import to add your style sheets?

IE8 doesn't seem to like the @import-property.

We used a global css file which imported the necessary styles. When moving all stylesheets to the header and including them with a normal link-tag, it works.

It's weird though, the regular bootstrap styling (buttons, backgrounds and such) got imported properly. The grid system was not. I guess Internet Explorer works in mysterious and retarded ways.